# tvOS Button Action

Tags: swift, uibutton, tvos

I create a UIButton in tvOS via Swift

```
let randomBtn = UIButton()
randomBtn.setTitle("Zufällig", forState: .Normal)
let RndNormal = UIImage(named: "RndNormal")
let RndHoover = UIImage(named: "RndHoover")
randomBtn.setImage(RndNormal, forState: .Normal)
randomBtn.setImage(RndHoover, forState: .Focused)
randomBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
randomBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Focused)

randomBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.click(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
randomBtn.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth - 150, y: 60 , width: 70 , height: 70)
self.view.addSubview(randomBtn)
```

But the action never get fired if I press the button, is there anything different in tvOS?

```
func click(sender: UIButton) {
    print("click")
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In tvOS for Button action `UIControlEvents` `TouchUpInside` will not call.

You have to use `UIControlEvents` `PrimaryActionTriggered` like below.

```
randomBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.click(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents. PrimaryActionTriggered)
```

Also Refer this link if you have any confusion

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17925

Comment: Thanks for this info, I was beating my head figuring this out.

Answer (score 3):

```
randomBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.click(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered)
```

Solved it, its just a other UIControlEvents